# cancel timer managed by spring container

Tags: java, spring, timer, scheduled-tasks, timertask

I have a `scheduled timer task` which is managed by `Spring container`. I can't figure a way to `kill it` once it throws some `exception` say `RuntimeException`. It keeps running for ever. Is there a way to access the `Timer object` and cancel it from the `code`?

This is my code:

```
    <bean id="myTimer" class="com.aspect.MyTimer"></bean>

<bean id="timerTaskFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="myTimer"></property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="doSomething"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="timerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="timerTaskFactoryBean"></property>
    <property name="period" value="5000"></property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean" id="timerBean">
    <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
        <list>
            <ref local="timerTask"></ref>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`Java class`

```
public class MyTimer  {


public void doSomething(){

     System.out.println("I am running...");

             try{
         throw  new RuntimeException(); 

     }
     catch(RuntimeException e){

          ScheduledTimerTask timer = (ScheduledTimerTask) App.appContext.getBeanFactory().getBean("timerTask");

            timer.getTimerTask().cancel();
             System.out.println("Timer cancelled due to..." +e); 


     }          




    }
```

}

Comment: Ok I figured out a way, not sure if this is ideal. Updated my code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to access the bean through the container and cancel it.